# On continuous images which are locally compact spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let K be a locally compact space and S a topological space. Suppose that K is a continuous image of S. Does it follow that K is a continuous image a locally compact subspace of S?

Comment: Generaly look at a stronger topology wich is not locally compact and the Id map.
If we do not require Housdorff this is trivial, take any non l.c. space and map it to the trivial topology or the co-finite topology.

Comment: For a Housdorf example take a compact set $X$ and look at the Id map from the inifinte product $X^\omega$ from the box (not locally comapct) to the product (compact) topology .